# Calculate the size of the set of all threshold functions from {1,...,k} to {0, 1}

Tags: functions, set-theory

Let $X = \{1,...,k\}$, for some integer $k$, a threshold function $h_{a}(x)$ is defined to be:
$
h_{a}(x)=\mathbb{1}_{[x<a]}
\begin{cases}1\text{ if }x\lt a,\\
0\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$

What is the length of the set of all threshold functions from $X\rightarrow \{0, 1\}$?

My calculation is infinite since:

If $h_{a}(x)$ is a function such that $h_{a}(1)=1$ and  $h_{a}(x)=0$ $\forall x\ne 1$ then we can choose any $1 \lt a \le 2$. Because there are infinitely many numbers between $(1, 2)$ so there's an infinite number of functions $h_{a}$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to have different rule but the two functions are equivalent, we just have to know what is the image of each element of the domain to define a function.

Hence $h_{1.1}=h_{1.2}$, they have different rules but if you examine the image of each element of the domain, they are the same.

Let's observe the function for a while, the function is a non-increasing function, once it drops to $0$, everything will become $0$.

Let me represent the function of all the elements as an array $[h(1), h(2), \ldots ,h(k-1), h(k)]$

We have $\{[1,1,\ldots,1, 1], [1,1,\ldots, 1,0], [1,1,\ldots, 0,0], \ldots,[1,0,\ldots, 0,0], [0,0,\ldots, 0,0] \}$.

Hence the cardinality is $k+1$.